# iReport socket creation error

Tags: ireport

My iReport installation (iReport 5.6.0, Win7) has recently started to throw `socket creation error` whenever I try to query the sample HSQLDB database. I tried reinstalling iReport and testing queries on different reports but it did not work. Does anyone know how to make the sample database work again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling Kaspersky worked for me. Must be a firewall issue.

Answer (score 0):

Open iReport as administrator!